# apache airflow scheduler not scheduling jobs

Tags: python, airflow

I'm working with `apache airflow 1.8.0`.

Here is output when I `backfill` the job.

```
[2017-04-13 09:42:55,857] {models.py:1126} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: example_bash_operator.runme_1 2017-04-13 13:43:00     [scheduled]>
[2017-04-13 09:42:55,857] {models.py:1126} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: example_bash_operator.runme_1 2017-04-13 13:43:00 [scheduled]>
[2017-04-13 09:42:55,857] {models.py:1126} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: example_bash_operator.runme_2 2017-04-13 13:45:00 [scheduled]>
[2017-04-13 09:42:55,858] {models.py:1126} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: example_bash_operator.runme_2 2017-04-13 13:45:00 [scheduled]>
[2017-04-13 09:42:55,858] {models.py:1126} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: example_bash_operator.runme_2 2017-04-13 13:43:00 [scheduled]>
[2017-04-13 09:42:55,858] {models.py:1126} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: example_bash_operator.runme_2 2017-04-13 13:43:00 [scheduled]>
[2017-04-13 09:42:55,858] {models.py:1126} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: example_bash_operator.also_run_this 2017-04-13 13:44:00 [scheduled]>
[2017-04-13 09:42:55,858] {models.py:1126} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: example_bash_operator.also_run_this 2017-04-13 13:44:00 [scheduled]>
[2017-04-13 09:42:55,864] {models.py:1120} INFO - Dependencies not met for <TaskInstance: example_bash_operator.run_after_loop 2017-04-13 13:44:00 [scheduled]>, dependency 'Trigger Rule' FAILED: Task's trigger rule 'all_success' requires all upstream tasks to have succeeded, but found 3 non-success(es). upstream_tasks_state={'skipped': Decimal('0'), 'successes': Decimal('0'), 'done': 0, 'upstream_failed': Decimal('0'), 'failed': Decimal('0')}, upstream_task_ids=['runme_0', 'runme_1', 'runme_2']
```

when I try to schedule any `DAG` it throws error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/bin/airflow", line 28, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 167, in backfill
    pool=args.pool)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 3330, in run
    job.run()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 200, in run
    self._execute()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 2021, in _execute
    raise AirflowException(err)
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: ---------------------------------------------------
```

Here is output about tasks.

```
BackfillJob is deadlocked. These tasks have succeeded:
set()
 These tasks have started:
{}
 These tasks have failed:
set()
 These tasks are skipped:
set()
 These tasks are deadlocked:
{<TaskInstance: example_bash_operator.runme_0 2017-04-13 13:44:00 [scheduled]>, <TaskInstance: example_bash_operator.runme_1 2017-04-13 13:44:00 [scheduled]>, <TaskInstance: example_bash_operator.runme_0 2017-04-13 13:46:00 [scheduled]>, <TaskInstance: example_bash_operator.runme_2 2017-04-13 13:44:00 [scheduled]>, <TaskInstance: example_bash_operator.also_run_this 2017-04-13 13:46:00 [scheduled]>, <TaskInstance: example_bash_operator.runme_0 2017-04-13 13:45:00 [scheduled]>, <TaskInstance: example_bash_operator.run_this_last 2017-04-13 13:46:00 [scheduled]>, <TaskInstance: example_bash_operator.runme_1 2017-04-13 13:46:00 [scheduled]>, <TaskInstance: example_bash_operator.runme_2 2017-04-13 13:46:00 [scheduled]>, <TaskInstance: example_bash_operator.run_after_loop 2017-04-13 13:46:00 [scheduled]>, <TaskInstance: example_bash_operator.also_run_this 2017-04-13 13:43:00 [scheduled]>, <TaskInstance: example_bash_operator.run_after_loop 2017-04-13 13:43:00 [scheduled]>, <TaskInstance: example_bash_operator.run_this_last 2017-04-13 13:45:00 [scheduled]>, <TaskInstance: example_bash_operator.also_run_this 2017-04-13 13:45:00 [scheduled]>, <TaskInstance: example_bash_operator.run_this_last 2017-04-13 13:43:00 [scheduled]>, <TaskInstance: example_bash_operator.runme_0 2017-04-13 13:43:00 [scheduled]>, <TaskInstance: example_bash_operator.runme_1 2017-04-13 13:45:00 [scheduled]>, <TaskInstance: example_bash_operator.run_after_loop 2017-04-13 13:45:00 [scheduled]>, <TaskInstance: example_bash_operator.runme_1 2017-04-13 13:43:00 [scheduled]>, <TaskInstance: example_bash_operator.runme_2 2017-04-13 13:45:00 [scheduled]>, <TaskInstance: example_bash_operator.runme_2 2017-04-13 13:43:00 [scheduled]>, <TaskInstance: example_bash_operator.also_run_this 2017-04-13 13:44:00 [scheduled]>, <TaskInstance: example_bash_operator.run_after_loop 2017-04-13 13:44:00 [scheduled]>, <TaskInstance: example_bash_operator.run_this_last 2017-04-13 13:44:00 [scheduled]>}
```

tested with **python 2.7** and **python 3.5**

used **SequentialExecutor** and **LocalExecutor**

**PS**. if I backfill the DAG at current time, it executes for once, and then throws the above error for all the scheduled tasks.

Comment: Facing similar issue with airflow 1.9 as well. Did anything work for you?

Comment: @mad_ To schedule jobs properly, these things need to be considered.
1) Make sure dag has a constant start time, not something like `datetime.utcnow()`.
2) Schedule interval is not set to `@None`.
3) Make sure there is no `backfill` for that dag earlier. If you backfill the dag the you need to clear that dag first by `airflow clear <dag_id>`.
let me know if this helps.

Comment: Well if I don't give the date argument as now() or datetime.datetime().now() then how will I schedule it programmatically? Do I need to pass the date manually because that was not the case in 1.7 or maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Also I am running trying to run dag in local scope inside the function

Comment: dag that are in global space will only be detected.

Comment: specify start time like this =>`datetime(2018, 4, 5, 5, 0)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your airflow instance is in deadlock state. The task which has failed is not allowing future runs of the task.

Airflow launches each task in each dag run as a new process and when the task falters and this is not handled deadlock situation arises

To resolve this situation you can do one of the following:

1. use `airflow clear <<dag_id>>` This will resolve the deadlock and allow future runs of the DAG/task
2. If above does not solve the issue, you would need to `use airflow resetdb` This would clear the airflow database and hence resolve the issue

In future,

- try and use `execution_timeout=timedelta(minutes=2)` set some timeout so that you have explicit control on operator
- Also, do provide a `on_failure_callback=handle_failure` which would cleanly exist the operator on failure

Hope this helps,

Cheers!